# Calculate $CA^{-1}$ given $AB$ and $CB$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A,B,C$ are two by two matrices. And given:
$$
AB=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
-1 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
CB=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0\\
0 & -1
    \end{pmatrix}
$$.
Find $CA^{-1}$.

I tried giving variables of each element in each matrix. But it seems dirty.

Comment: Hint: $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1} A^{-1}$.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Thanks! I got the answer.